# How to determine how many minutes has passed in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have variable which I populate from JSON formated data. 
Something like:
`var time=my_data[data.results[i].id].time;`
This gives me time from database in this format : `2012-06-19 15:48:18.140`

How can save in some other variable value for example `active` if the time between a value that I get from database and time which is present(now) is less then 5 min and `inactive` if it is more then 5 min passed

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for javascript Date

Date Constructor accepts a [date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). I tried yours in chrome console it works fine.
Then you can use [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970

Finally

```
var past = new Date(yourTimeString).getTime();
var fiveMin = 1000 * 60 * 5; 
var isPast = (new Date().getTime() - past < fiveMin)?false:true;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var otherVariable = ((new Date().getTime() - time) < fiveMinutes) ? "active": "inactive";
```

But I'm unsure of the type you get from your JSON, so you might need to use this variant instead :

```
var fiveMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var otherVariable = ((new Date().getTime() - new Date(time).getTime()) < fiveMinutes) ? "active": "inactive";
```

Comment: Not the format, the type : String ? Date ? Has your JSON passed through JSON.decode() ? (or even eval ? though it's not considered good, some people do this)

Comment: OK that's what I figured ;-) go for second version

Comment: So you've accepted the other answer, which has been posted clearly after mine, as an almost exact duplicate... weird. Whatever.

Comment: yours didn't worked. I don't know why. And the above answer is a bit simpler. no hard feelings